AWS QuickSight on Athena: normalized or denormalized?
I have a data pipeline that aggregates and cleanses data from multiple sources and loads it into S3 within parquet files.  I want to create some interactive visualizations on this data using AWS Quicksight.
The data is a few tens of terabytes, too large to load completely into Quicksight SPICE.  My plan is therefore to use Athena as the Quicksight data source.
I'm trying to decide:

whether my underlying data should be normalized or denormalized.
if normalized, should I create an Athena view on the normalized tables that presents Quicksight with a denormalized view of the data, or just point Quicksight to the individual tables.

About the data
My data consists of suppliers, buyers and products, and the prices paid by a suppliers to a buyers for various products.
There are a few hundred buyers, tens of thousands of suppliers, and several thousand products.  So while not every buyer buys every products from every supplier, we're still talking billions of rows for the combinations of those three.  In addition to an ID and name, suppliers and buyers have a few other descriptors such as location (city, state, zipcode) and type.  Products are just a SKU number and one-line text description.
How will users interact with the data?
A user is going to want to filter down to a subset of the data: for example view a box plot of prices for a subset of products paid by buyers to suppliers in a given city.
Since these are interactive, response time is an important consideration.
So... should I combine all my data into a single giant denormalized table, or should I normalize it?  What decision criteria should I consider?
